# Alinear inputs formulario HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Hola buenas tengo un problema con el formulario y es que quiero alinear los inputs a la derecha.

```
nombre    : input
apellidos : input input
```

actualmente se me ve asi:

```
nombre
input
apellidos 
input 
input
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bajud5z0/1/
muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy simple, te paso un ejemplo, debes poner cada campo en una columna diferente.

En el ejemplo he puesto un `.col-sm-2` para el `label`, y `.col-sm-5` para los campos de formulario; todo dentro de un `.form-group`

No te olvides de ejecutar y ampliar para ver el ejemplo a pantalla completa.
Dime si hay algo que no entiendas.

```css
/* Link boostrap */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input-nombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input-apellido" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Apellidos</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-apellido-1" placeholder="Apellido Uno">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-apellido-2" placeholder="Apellido Dos">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar formulario</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Además viendo tu codigo:

- le falta el `class="form-control"` de bootstrap para cada campo de
  formulario
- tienes que usar `.form-group`para cada campo con su label

Answer (score 1):

Esto podría valerte (no he usado bootstrap):
https://jsfiddle.net/c2hm32bf/3/

Comment: Franxo te sugiero Revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacerlo siguiendo éste ejemplo:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
    <form action="" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="nombre" class="control-label col-sm-3">Nombre</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                 <input type="text" id="nombre" class="form-control">
              </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```